# How to use custom CheckBox in PreferenceScreen on Android

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-preferences

I want use `PreferenceScreen` in my application for set some of settings. I've customized this page, and set layout for any preferences. all of preferences is OK, but `CheckBoxPreferences`, and when I click on it does not show any reaction, this is ture in every time. i can set is false!!! i've set ***`android:id="@+android:id/checkbox"`*** for custom CheckBox.
**CheckBox custom xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff">

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/summary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+android:id/title"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="#c0c0c0"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+android:id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**PreferenceSreen xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:example="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:sample="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="setting_main_subtitle_show"
            android:layout="@layout/pref_checkbox_layout"
            android:summary="Summary Text"
            android:title="Title" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

**AppPreference java code :**

```
public class AppPreference {
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private Context context;

    private static final String KeyShowSubTitle = "setting_main_subtitle_show";

    public AppPreference(Context context){
        this.sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        this.editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        this.context = context;
    }

    public Boolean getShowSubTitle(){
        return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(KeyShowSubTitle, true);
    }
}
```

**MainPage java code :**

```
Boolean show_subTitle = appPreference.getShowSubTitle();
if (show_subTitle == true){
    /// SubTitle Text
    toolbar.setSubtitle(appPreference.getSubTitleText());
} else {
    toolbar.setSubtitle("");
}
```

How can i fix this problem and use custom `CheckBox` in `PreferenceScreen` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
custom_layout.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CheckBox xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+android:id/checkbox"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="true" 
android:button="@drawable/android_button"/>
```

default.xml

```
<CheckBoxPreference 
 android:key="@string/Drop_Option"
 android:title="Close after call drop" 
 android:defaultValue="true"
 android:widgetLayout="@layout/custom_layout"/>
```

Comment: thanks, can you send me `@drawable/android_button` code? thanks you

Comment: refer http://www.vankouteren.eu/blog/2011/09/custom-checkboxes-for-checkboxpreferences-on-android/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTag()` and `getTag()` methods to solve this issue.
From your xml file, add `android:tag="integer"` to CheckBoxPreference and get that integer in your java file by using getMethod and do your stuff and use the setMethod and then save it in shared preferences.